# Hover on CardContent in Material-Ui on Internet Explorer not working

Tags: material-ui

I am trying to give border-bottom when hovered on CardContent in Material-UI. It is working fine in Chrome and Firefox. But, on internet explorer hovered style is not visible. I have even tried  using Typography instead of span , then also hovered style is not implemented in Internet Explorer. Below is the code

```
import React, { PureComponent } from 'react';
import PropTypes from 'prop-types';
import { withStyles  } from '@material-ui/core/styles';
import {
  Card,
  CardActionArea,
  CardContent,
  CardMedia,
  Typography,
} from '@material-ui/core';

const useStyles = theme => ({
  card: {
    margin:'15px',
    borderRadius: '0 0 15px 15px',
    backgroundColor: '#F5F4F9',
    boxShadow:'none',
  },
  actionArea: {
    "&:hover $focusHighlight": {
      opacity: 0
    }
  },
  focusHighlight: {},
  paragraph: {
    margin: '0 0 1.5em'
  },
  cardContentTitle: {
    fontSize: '1.25rem',
    fontWeight: '500',
    lineHeight: '1.5',
    margin: '0 0 0.75em',
    wordBreak:'break-word',
    [theme.breakpoints.up('sm')]: {
      fontSize: '1.1rem'
    }
  },
    cardContentSpan: {
      '&:hover': {
        color: '#000',
        borderBottom:'3px solid #000',
      },
    },
  cardContent: {
    backgroundColor: '#F5F4F9',
    borderRadius: '0 0 15px 15px',
    padding: '12px 16px'
  },
  cardContentDescription: {
    margin: '0 0 1.5em',
    fontSize: '1rem',
    lineHeight: '1.5',
    color: '#22205B',
    wordBreak:'break-word'
  }
});
class BlogContent extends PureComponent {  
  render(){
      const {classes} = this.props;
      return(
        <Card 
          className={classes.card}
          >
              <CardActionArea
                  classes={{
                    root: classes.actionArea,
                    focusHighlight: classes.focusHighlight
                  }}
              >
                <CardMedia
                  component="img"
                  alt="Image"
                  width="1000"
                  height="332"
                  image={this.props.image}
                />
                <CardContent className={classes.cardContent}>
                  <Typography 
                    gutterBottom 
                    variant="h5" 
                    component="h3"
                    className={classes.cardContentTitle}
                  >
                    <span
                        className={classes.cardContentSpan}                    
                        >
                          Derfor bør du droppe epositum i depositum
                    </span>
                  </Typography>
                  <Typography 
                    component="p"
                    className={classes.cardContentDescription}>
                      D oppretter du enkelt her, uavhengig om du er utleier eller leietaker. For å sikre oss om at du er den...
                    </Typography>
                </CardContent>
              </CardActionArea>
          </Card>
      );
    };
  }

export default withStyles(useStyles)(BlogContent);
```

Comment: What is the version of IE you are using?

Comment: I am using Internet Explorer 11